# Flash slider won't fit screen

Tags: html, css, flash

I've created a very easy looking slider using Adobe Flash. This is four big pictures containing some text, which will be placed in a HTML-website using Dreamweaver. The size is the problem. The picture is suppose to fit the entire width, and like 50% of the heigh. When I "Preview in browser", it won't fit the screen, and you have to "scroll" around to see the entire picture. Any suggestions?

Comment: Any suggestions? **Show the problem code**. No one can A̶n̶s̶w̶e̶r̶ guess what's wrong inside your mystery code to avoid the unwanted bad result... Read [**How To Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and do what it says to avoid any more downvotes (which could Close your question)

Answer (score 1):

How the percentage is applied depends on a number of things, some of them being:

- [Box-sizing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing?v=example)
- [Display](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display?v=control) value of parent and child
- Whether the parent has its [width](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/width?v=control) set
- Whether the parent and child are in the same [flow](http://marksheet.io/css-the-flow.html)

Please check against this list to find out what the issue is in your case.